# Which vector threw index out of range exception?

Tags: c++, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I would like to access a reference to the `std::vector` which throws an out of range exception, or at least the line number where the exception was thrown (similar to Java's stack traces). Here is an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> vec1;
std::vector<int> vec2;
vec1.push_back(1);
vec2.push_back(2);
try
{

    std::cout << vec1.at(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec2.at(1) << std::endl;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // e.lineNumber()? e.creator_object()?
    std::cout << "The following vector is out of range: " << ? << std::endl;
    // or...
    std::cout << "There was an error on the following line: " << ? << std::endl;
}
```

I know this example is trivial, but I hope it demonstrates what functionality I'm looking for.

EDIT: Implementation, from g++ --version: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)

Comment: No such thing built into c++, maybe your implementation has something though, but since we don't know it...

Comment: Use two try-catch statements, once per access.

Comment: Line number won't give you anything - it'll be in STL header for vector... To start with, you can use two `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Unlike Java, C++ does not build a debugger into your application. If you want a stack trace, run the program in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do that yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> vec1;
std::vector<int> vec2;

vec1.push_back(1);
vec2.push_back(2);

try
{
    std::cout << vec1.at(1) << std::endl;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "The following vector is out of range: " << "vec1" << std::endl;
}

try
{
    std::cout << vec2.at(1) << std::endl;
}
catch(std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << "The following vector is out of range: " << "vec2" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In this specific synthetic example it doesn't matter. And maybe "safer" is not the best word to use here, but what I meant is: when you `catch(...)` you not only don't have exception details, like `what()`, you don't know what you've caught at all, how are you going to handle it? Also, if you compile with MSVC++ with `/EHsc` your `catch(...)` will catch structured exceptions like Access Violation or Stack Overflow, which is probably not what you expect to catch and/or handle.